# want single asynctask for whole project

Tags: android

I have a 3 activity. all these three activity has same `AsyncTask`. I want the single AsyncTask for all activity so i can pass the activity as parameter to `AsyncTask` constructor. please guide me.

Comment: all 3 activities AsyncTask does same task?

Answer (score 1):

create a constructor for your asyn-task, and pass the context and required parameters to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the context in the constructor of your AsyncTask class, and use it throughout in the class like in progress dialog etc